# table displayed by ajax not accessible by script in the caller page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to be able to dblclick on a row/record of a mysql table to open another window for modifying the record.
If  'mytable' is printed from within the php page the script see its elements and it is ok.
But if  'mytable' is printed by

`xhttp.open("GET", "get_table.php?q="+str, true)`

its elements are not accessible by the script below.

Thanks for the solution!

---

Code:

```
<script>
var p = {
         onload: function()  
         {
            var rows = document.getElementById("mytable").rows;
            for(var i = 0, ceiling = rows.length; i < ceiling; i++) 
            {
              rows[i].ondblclick = function() 
               { 
                          myrec=this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                          if (nreg||null)
                          window.open('c_modif_reg.php?nreg='+myrec);    
               }
             }
           }
          };
</script>
```

Comment: Go read up on _event delegation_.

Comment: As @04FS said you should look for event delegation, here is an [example](https://jsbin.com/hasurop/2/edit?js,output)

Comment: thank you. But I am a very newbie and not able to put together the code of the example to make it work. Could you maybe paste for me the html and script tabs, please?